# Reformed Theology

Tags: reformed-theology, denomination-survey, presbyterianism, non-denominational

Can anyone point me to a scholarly article or book that clearly, definitively, and ***authoritatively*** defines what qualifies a person or denomination as "reformed"? I've heard Presbyterians claim that they are the only true reformed denomination; if this is the case, what authority is this based on, and why is it not just referred to either Presbyterianism (Presbyterian Theology) or Reformed Theology? For example, I consider myself a reformed, covenantal Calvinist (pretty much a non-denominational Calvinist), but since I believe in credo vs. paedobaptism, I've been told I am not reformed.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no authority. If someone wants to use some unusual or eclectic definition, no one can stop them.

Comment: It’s kind of like the whole discussion as to what constitutes a Christian. Every "reformed" tradition has its own definition of "reformed," so the only reliable way to determine if a theology is truly "reformed" is whether or not it identifies as such. Self-identification is the only defining criterion that can possibly be anywhere near acceptable to everyone.